# if not working with decrement/increment

Tags: php, if-statement, decrement

Hi I´m new in php and in one book i found this:

```
$x = 0;    
if ($x-- == 0) echo $x;
```

in book they write it should write -1 to my page, because decremenet was done after comparison and before the command exho was executed. I understand why it is that, but when I type it into my editor it's giving me error because it's understanding $x-- as one and $x as another variable. Where's problem?

Comment: what does the `error` says?

Comment: you might have typed it wrong.. just a copy&paste from your sample: http://codepad.org/2BTjh3qt and it does show -1 as output

Comment: this gives me -1 http://phpfiddle.org/api/raw/nkq-1f7

Comment: Regardless of what your book says, please don't modify variables in an `if` statement. As you've seen, that's easy to mistype and will be hell for anyone (even you, after months) reading that code.

Comment: some editors may give error since they are expecting variable/value. you can try `if (($x--) == 0) echo $x;`.

Comment: @mabi the code sample works well to prove the concept

Comment: @mabi he's only trying to learn a concept. So it's ok. He is probably trying to see the difference between --$x and $x--

Comment: Add `echo $x` to your last line of code and see what the output is

Comment: What's your editor and OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Basic Steps :**

**Step 1:** (get **Notepad++**)

Go to http://notepad-plus-plus.org/ and download **Notepad++**.
Notepad++ is a free (as in "free speech" and also as in "free beer") source code editor and Notepad replacement that supports several languages. Running in the MS Windows environment, its use is governed by GPL License.

**Step 2:** (type the code)

type and save as "filename.php" in "www directory"

```
<?php

$x = 0;    
if ($x-- == 0) echo $x;

?>
```

**Step 3:** (enJoy !)

Check the result

> Expected Output :
>   -1 //  this is what i got! :D

Answer (score 2):

$x-- is postdecrement that is the $x value will be still 0. when you went away from the statement then only the $x value should be change. so if statement is working fine. the echo value will be -1.

7-isnotbad answer is correct.